# QUANTSTRAT - apply.paramset issue

Tags: optimization, quantstrat

I am trying to optimize MACD parameters for a trading strategy but unfortunately I am stuck with `paramset.label` value. This is the code:

```
################################# MACD PARAMETERS OPTIMIZATION

.fastMA <- (20:40)
.slowMA <- (30:70)
.nsamples = 10

strat.st <- 'volStrat'

# Paramset

add.distribution(strat.st,
                 paramset.label = 'EMA',
                 component.type = 'indicator',
                 component.label = 'macd.out', 
                 variable = list(n = .fastMA),
                 label = 'nFast'
)

add.distribution(strat.st,
                 paramset.label = 'EMA',
                 component.type = 'indicator',
                 component.label = 'macd.out', 
                 variable = list(n = .slowMA),
                 label = 'nSlow'
)

add.distribution.constraint(strat.st,
                            paramset.label = 'EMA',
                            distribution.label.1 = 'nFast',
                            distribution.label.2 = 'nSlow',
                            operator = '<',
                            label = 'nFast<nSlow'
)

results <- apply.paramset(strat.st, 
                          paramset.label = 'EMA', 
                          portfolio = portfolio2.st, 
                          account = account.st, 
                          nsamples = .nsamples, 
                          verbose = TRUE)

stats <- results$tradeStats

print(stats)
```

When I run it, this error occurs for every sample:

```
    evaluation # 1:
$param.combo
    nFast nSlow
379    23    51

[1] "Processing param.combo 379"
    nFast nSlow
379    23    51
result of evaluating expression:
<simpleError in strategy[[components.type]][[index]]: subscript out of bounds>
got results for task 1
numValues: 1, numResults: 1, stopped: FALSE
returning status FALSE
```

And then, for the last one, this is the error:

```
evaluation # 10:
$param.combo
    nFast nSlow
585    40    60

[1] "Processing param.combo 585"
    nFast nSlow
585    40    60
result of evaluating expression:
<simpleError in strategy[[components.type]][[index]]: subscript out of bounds>
got results for task 10
numValues: 10, numResults: 10, stopped: FALSE
first call to combine function
evaluating call object to combine results:
  fun(result.1, result.2, result.3, result.4, result.5, result.6, 
    result.7, result.8, result.9, result.10)
error calling combine function:
<simpleError in fun(result.1, result.2, result.3, result.4, result.5, result.6,     result.7, result.8, result.9, result.10): attempt to select less than one element>
numValues: 10, numResults: 10, stopped: TRUE
```

I really don't understand how can I fix it. 
Can anyone how can I solve this?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give the code before OPTIMIZATION part, so here is only my guess direction.

I understand you want to test 20:40 and 30:70, but in your OPTIMIZATION code, you add 2 distribution both pointing to " component.label = 'macd.out' ".

I did similar test, although they both use MA type indicators, they generally should not point to the same MA data(" component.label = 'macd.out' "), these code worked one distribution points to "component.label = 'fast'" and another points to "component.label = 'slow'" as they are pointing different datas so that they can be compared.

You can try to debug in this direction.